# Newcomer to Node, how to understand process.nextTick()

Tags: node.js

code1:

```
function foo() {
    console.log('foo');
}
process.nextTick(foo);
console.log('bar');
```

code2:

```
function foo() {
    console.log('foo');
}
foo();
console.log('bar');
```

The first piece of code output:

```
bar
foo
```

and the second is opposite:

```
foo
bar
```

why?

My question is :

1. How to understand "what process.nextTick() actually does is defer the execution of an action till the next pass around the event loop"
2. Actually, I don't know the concept of 'event', console.log('bar') is an event? foo() is an event? process.nextTick(foo) is an event?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process.nextTick(foo)` schedules `foo()` to be called after the current thread of JS execution finishes.  It does this by essentially inserting a call to `foo()` at the front of the event queue.  When the current thread of JS execution finishes, the node.js engine will pull the next event off the event queue and run it.  This will cause you to get your output:

```
bar
foo
```

Because `console.log('bar')` is part of the current thread of execution so that will finish before the next event in the event loop is serviced.

So, in words, here's what the `code1` example is doing:

1. Define `foo` function (this is actually done by the parser before anything executes)
2. Run `process.nextTick(foo)` which schedules `foo()` to be run after the rest of this thread of Javascript finishes by inserting an event in the event queue.  All callbacks or functions to be run in the future are scheduled this way in node.js (via the event queue).  node.js is an event driven environment.
3. Run `console.log('bar')`.
4. Current thread of JS finishes execution.
5. System pulls next event from the event queue and runs it.
6. This next event is the call to `foo()` from the `process.nextTick()` call.
7. `foo()` runs.

In your `code2` example, this is just sequential execution.  Nothing is inserted in the event queue at all.  `foo()` is executed and then when that function returns, the `console.log('bar')` is executed.

---

So `process.nextTick()` is used to explicitly schedule something to run later after the current thread of JS execution has finished.

It's similar to `setTimeout()`, but `process.nextTick()` runs as soon as possible after the current thread of execution whereas `setTimeout()` can be set with a specific time delay.

---

It appears your code example is taken from this article: [Understanding process.nextTick()](https://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick).  There is a lot more explanation in that article.

Another reference: [What are the proper use cases for process.nextTick in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112914/what-are-the-proper-use-cases-for-process-nexttick-in-node-js)

Comment: Thanks. One more question, "insert at the front of the event queue", then  the Node pull the end of the event in the queue? (first in first out)

Comment: @watchdog - Usually the event queue is FIFO for events of all the same type.  But, `setTimeout()`, `setImmediate()` and `process.nextTick()` each have their own way of inserting into the event queue which determines what they jump in front of.  There are articles that compare all three.  `nextTick()` goes pretty much at the front of the event queue (before other I/O events).  `setImmediate()` goes after other I/O events in the queue and `setTimeout()` is used to schedule a specific time in the future and always after everything else in the queue already.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much